# How do I interface with midi files in Darkwave?

Tags: midi

I've had oodles of fun with Darkwave so far, mostly by writing simple midi on a per-instrument basis, but I do not see how to save that midi and apply it to, say, other instruments.  How can I save and play midi files in Darkwave so that I don't have to duplicate my efforts so much?

Comment: someone with reputation plz add Darkwave tag.

Comment: You'd be surprised how ineffective searching for _darkwave "midi file"_ is.